# How do i replace repeating values in a row with a blank?

Tags: mysql, repeat

I have a query which returns a product, and the number of media assigned to a product, In the Campaign Amount column the values are being repeated for the same product, how do I make it just show the Campaign Amount once and then "blank" the rest of the times for that same product?? Im thinking on the lines of not eliminating repeating groups but merely showing the value once and then replacing the repeating values with a "blank" value

A link to the screenshot im talking about is:

http://www.quickshare.co.za/files/jppibi73/Screenshot_3.png.html

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would help if you posted a `create table` or some sample data. May be your current SQL query too.

Comment: added a link to a screenshot of my report

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that the string "Product" is a nique ID of a product, you can get only a single instance and he number of repeating records with the following:

```
SELECT Product,
    AVG(`Campaign Amount`) AS Amount,
    COUNT(*) AS Occurrence
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Product
ORDER BY Product
```

Although I think these are not the real field names, but here you go.

Comment: please see my answer on top,i posted my query